# Redux async requests with fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch, race-condition, redux, es6-promise

I'm stuck in a wierd behaviour that I can't really debug.

The store dispatch the action that perform the login request passing username and password. Then when the response is ready I store the credentials in the redux store. When I need to perform an authorized request I set those parameters in the header request. When I receive the response I update the credentials in the store with the new ones that I get from the response.
When I try to perform the third request it will respond unauthorized. I figured out that this is because all the parameters passed to my action generator setCredentials are null. I can't understand why also because if  I add a debugger before the return statement of my setCredentials function and I wait some seconds before restart the execution I found out that the parameters aren't null anymore. I was thinking about the fact that the request is async but being inside a then statement the response should be ready right? I've also notice that fetch sent two request for each one.
Here the code for more clarity.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const initialState = {
  currentUser: {
    credentials: {},
    user: {}
  },
  test: {},
  users: []
}

export const SUBMIT_LOGIN = 'SUBMIT_LOGIN'
export const SET_USER = 'SET_USER'
export const TEST = 'TEST'
export const SET_USERS = 'SET_USERS'
export const SET_CREDENTIALS = 'SET_CREDENTIALS'

//actions
const submitLogin = () => (dispatch) => {
  return postLoginRequest()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setCredentials(
        response.headers.get('access-token'),
        response.headers.get('client'),
        response.headers.get('expiry'),
        response.headers.get('token-type'),
        response.headers.get('uid')
      ));
      return response
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(
      (user) => dispatch(setUser(user.data)),
    );
}

const performRequest = (api) => (dispatch) => {
  return api()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setCredentials(
        response.headers.get('access-token'),
        response.headers.get('client'),
        response.headers.get('expiry'),
        response.headers.get('token-type'),
        response.headers.get('uid')
      ));
      return response
    })
    .then(response => {return response.json()})
    .then(
      (users) => {
        dispatch(setUsers(users.data))
      },
    );
}

const setUsers = (users) => {
  return {
    type: SET_USERS,
    users
  }
}

const setUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: SET_USER,
    user
  }
}

const setCredentials = (
  access_token,
  client,
  expiry,
  token_type,
  uid
) => {
  debugger
  return {
    type: SET_CREDENTIALS,
    credentials: {
      'access-token': access_token,
      client,
      expiry,
      'token-type': token_type,
      uid
    }
  }
}

//////////////
const currentUserInitialState = {
  credentials: {},
  user: {}
}

const currentUser = (state = currentUserInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.user})
    case SET_CREDENTIALS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {credentials: action.credentials})
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  currentUser,
  test
})

const getAuthorizedHeader = (store) => {
  const credentials = store.getState().currentUser.credentials
  const headers = new Headers(credentials)
  return headers
}

//store creation

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunk
)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);

const postLoginRequest = () => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
  })
}

const getUsers = () => {
  const autorizedHeader = getAuthorizedHeader(store)
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/users',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers : autorizedHeader
    }
  )
}

const getWorks = () => {
  const autorizedHeader = getAuthorizedHeader(store)
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/work_offers',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers : autorizedHeader
    }
  )
}
// this request works fine
store.dispatch(submitLogin())

// this request works fine
setTimeout(() => {
  store.dispatch(performRequest(getUsers))
}, 3000)

// this fails
setTimeout(() => {
  store.dispatch(performRequest(getWorks))
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Have you verified that *all* your endpoints return those headers and not just the login one? Maybe when you `performRequest(getUsers)`, it comes back with empty headers.

Comment: Yes. Verified. Every authorized request to my backend return those headers. @dan

Comment: Alas, hard to guess from the code. If you can create an isolated example that reproduces the issue in JSBin I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do it. @dan

Comment: Hi Dan. I create this [repo](https://github.com/simoneromanelli/redux_async_attempt) for the test. Thanks @DanAbramov

Comment: The file is empty: https://github.com/simoneromanelli/redux_async_attempt/blob/master/app/index.js. Can you please add the code *and* instructions to reproduce your issue?

Comment: My bad. I messed up with my branches. Now it is ok. @DanAbramov

Answer (score 2):

I should have clarified that when I asked

> Have you verified that all your endpoints return those headers and not just the login one? Maybe when you `performRequest(getUsers)`, it comes back with empty headers.

I didn’t just mean the server logic. I meant opening the Network tab in DevTools and actually **verifying** whether your responses contain the headers you expect. It turns out `getUsers()` headers do not always contain the credentials:

[image]

Now that we confirmed this happens, let’s see why.

You dispatch `submitLogin()` and `performRequest(getUsers)` *roughly* at the same time. In the cases when the error is reproduced, the problem is in the following sequence of steps:

1. You fire off `submitLogin()`
2. You fire off `performRequest(getUsers)` before `submitLogin()` comes back
3. `submitLogin()` comes back and stores the credentials from the response headers
4. `performRequest(getUsers)` comes back but **since it started before credentials were available, the server responds with empty headers, and those empty credentials are stored instead of the existing ones**
5. `performRequest(getWorks)` is now requested without the credentials

There are several fixes for this problem.

### Don’t Let Old Unauthorized Requests Overwrite the Credentials

I don’t think it really makes sense to overwrite existing good credentials with the empty ones, does it? You can either check that they are non-empty in `performRequest` before dispatching:

```
const performRequest = (api) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return api()
    .then(response => {
      if (response.headers.get('access-token')) {
        dispatch(setCredentials(
          response.headers.get('access-token'),
          response.headers.get('client'),
          response.headers.get('expiry'),
          response.headers.get('token-type'),
          response.headers.get('uid')
        ));
      }
      return response
    })
    .then(response => {return response.json()})
    .then(
      (users) => {
        dispatch(setUsers(users.data))
      },
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you can do ignore invalid credentials in the reducer itself:

```
case SET_CREDENTIALS:
  if (action.credentials['access-token']) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {credentials: action.credentials})
  } else {
    return state
  }
```

Both ways are fine and depend on the conventions that make more sense to you.

### Wait Before Performing Requests

In any case, do you really want to fire `getUsers()` *before* you have the credentials? If not, fire off the requests only until the credentials are available. Something like this:

```
store.dispatch(submitLogin()).then(() => {
  store.dispatch(performRequest(getUsers))
  store.dispatch(performRequest(getWorks))
})
```

If it’s not always feasible or you would like more sophisticated logic like retrying failed requests, I suggest you to look at [Redux Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) which lets you use powerful concurrency primitives to schedule this kind of work.

Comment: I imagined this could be the problem but I don't understand why this happens since `performRequest(getUsers)` or `performRequest(getUsers)`  are fired of in a `setTimeout` function. I supposed that in 3 seconds the login request should return the response.
Anyway do you think this is a good way to manage the credentials (I mean saving them in the store)? Thanks you very much for your time. @dan

Comment: Well, relying on response coming *exactly* during some period of time is not very wise, at least in production code :-). You can put more logs and check whether my diagnosis is correct. Unfortunately I don’t have time right now to open your project again and do it for you :-). Yes, the approach seems fine.